# grid rows and its margin

Tags: css, css-grid

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="a">x</div>
            <div class="b"></div>
            <div class="c"></div>
        </div>
        <style>
            .container {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-rows: min-content 300px 50vw;
            }

            .a {
                margin-bottom: 0px;
            }
            .b {
                margin-top: 20px;
                margin-bottom: 0px;
            }

            .c {
                margin-bottom: 50px;
            }
        </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

I found that margin will compress `grid-template-rows`, the rows height will decrease when that row add

margin.

EX:

`<div class="b"></div>`  has been set row height 300px, but its height is only 280px.

`<div class="c"></div>`  has been set row height 50vw, but its height is not 50vw.

I want set distance between two div, but margin compress itself.

Comment: You can use `grid-gap` property on `.container `.

Comment: 280px + 20px margin-top fills the row that is 300px ... idem with 50vw minus the margin of the element itself . rows are the size you set them ;)